# MongoDB C# - Unhandled mongo expression type: 'Pipeline

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core, nosql

I'm having this error while trying to run this query with LINQ on MongoDB:

```
var instruction = billingHistorycollection.AsQueryable(new AggregateOptions { AllowDiskUse = true });
var query = await instruction.Where(x => 
    x.billing_account_id == new ObjectId(filter.id)
    && x.billing_kind == "PAYMENT"
    && x.state == "SUCCESSFUL"
    && x.issue_date >= DateHelper.StartOfDay(filter.firstDayOfMonth)
)
.GroupBy(x => new 
{
    service_id = x.service_id,
    month = x.issue_date.Month
})
.Select(z => new {
    month = z.Key.month,
    service_id = z.Key.service_id,
    is_document = z.Sum(x => x.billing_itens.Count(y => y != null)),
    is_non_document = z.Sum(x => x.billing_itens.Count(y => y == null)),
    request_count = z.Count()
})
.OrderBy(k => k.month)
.ThenBy(x => x.service_id)
.ToListAsync();
```

After running a lot of tests, I found out that these two lines are the problem:

```
is_document = z.Sum(x => x.billing_itens.Count(y => y != null)),
is_non_document = z.Sum(x => x.billing_itens.Count(y => y == null))
```

`billing_itens` is an array of strings that can either contain the name of the document or `null` if the document wasn't identified. So what I am trying to accomplish is a total count of how many documents and how many not documents were registered, grouped by month.

The query runs perfectly if I keep only one of the lines. So I can either run the first sum and get the total number of documents identified, or run the second and get the total count of not documents, but not the two together. I also tried the following code:

```
total_count = z.Sum(x => x.billing_itens.Count()),
document_count = z.Sum(x => x.billing_itens.Count(y => y != null))
```

Doesn't work either.

The project is developed with .NET Core 2.2 and MongoDB.Driver 2.9.2. I tried updating to the 2.10 version, but it didn't work.

Can someone explain me why this happens?

**Edit**

Also, this is the full stacktrace of the error:

```
at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionComparer.Compare(Expression a, Expression b)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.FindIndex(Int32 startIndex, Int32 count, Predicate`1 match)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.CorrelatedGroupRewriter.VisitCorrelatedGroup(CorrelatedExpression node)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.CorrelatedGroupRewriter.VisitCorrelated(CorrelatedExpression node)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Expressions.ExtensionExpressionVisitor.VisitSelect(SelectExpression node)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Expressions.ExtensionExpressionVisitor.VisitOrderBy(OrderByExpression node)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Expressions.ExtensionExpressionVisitor.VisitPipeline(PipelineExpression node)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.Pipeline.PipelineBinder.Bind(Expression node, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.MongoQueryProviderImpl`1.Prepare(Expression expression)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.MongoQueryProviderImpl`1.Translate(Expression expression)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.MongoQueryProviderImpl`1.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.MongoQueryableImpl`2.ToCursorAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.IAsyncCursorSourceExtensions.ToListAsync[TDocument](IAsyncCursorSource`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at {...}.Services.BillingService.GetCharts(ChartFilter filter) in {...}\\Services\\BillingServices.cs:line 450
```

Comment: When you say, billing_itens is an array of strings that can either contain the name of the document or null if the document wasn't identified.. does that mean it will always be an array that will contain either strings or null or both.. and that billing_itens can itself be a null ?

Comment: The array will always contain something. It might be a null value or a string, but the array itself is never null.